# How to add to beginning Python path in bash

Tags: python, pythonpath, python-import, bash

Here is my `.bash_profile`

```
PYTHONPATH=".:/home/miki725/django/django:$PYTHONPATH"
export PYTHONPATH
```

So then I open python however the directory I add in `.bash_profile` is not the first one:

```
Python 2.4.3 (#1, Sep 21 2011, 20:06:00) 
[GCC 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-51)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> for i in sys.path:
...     print i
... 

/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c9-py2.4.egg
/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/flup-1.0.2-py2.4.egg
/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.3c1-py2.4-linux-i686.egg
/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/django_form_utils-0.1.7-py2.4.egg
/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/mechanize-0.2.1-py2.4.egg
/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Django-1.2.1-py2.4.egg
/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/mercurial-1.6-py2.4-linux-i686.egg
/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/lxml-2.2.7-py2.4-linux-i686.egg
/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/django_registration-0.7-py2.4.egg
/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/sorl_thumbnail-3.2.5-py2.4.egg
/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/South-0.7.2-py2.4.egg
/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/django_keyedcache-1.4_1-py2.4.egg
/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/django_livesettings-1.4_3-py2.4.egg
/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/django_app_plugins-0.1.1-py2.4.egg
/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/django_signals_ahoy-0.1_2-py2.4.egg
/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/pycrypto-2.3-py2.4-linux-i686.egg
/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/django_threaded_multihost-1.4_0-py2.4.egg
/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/PIL-1.1.7-py2.4-linux-i686.egg
/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/pyOpenSSL-0.11-py2.4-linux-i686.egg
/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/ZSI-2.0_rc3-py2.4.egg
/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/PyXML-0.8.4-py2.4-linux-i686.egg
/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/pyquery-0.6.1-py2.4.egg
/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/pip-1.0.1-py2.4.egg
/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/virtualenv-1.6.1-py2.4.egg
/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/simplejson-2.1.6-py2.4-linux-i686.egg
/home/miki725
/home/miki725/django/django
/usr/lib/python24.zip
/usr/lib/python2.4
/usr/lib/python2.4/plat-linux2
/usr/lib/python2.4/lib-tk
/usr/lib/python2.4/lib-dynload
/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages
/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Numeric
/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/PIL
/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/gtk-2.0
>>> 
>>> 
>>> 
>>> 
>>> import django
>>> django.__file__
'/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Django-1.2.1-py2.4.egg/django/__init__.pyc'
>>>
```

How can I add to a python path in `.bash_profile` so it would be in the beginning. This is for shared hosting. I need to be able to import my django install instead of using system default.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet is to modify `sys.path` at runtime. In a shared hosting enviroment it's common to do this in your .wsgi file. You could do something like this:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/home/miki725/django/django')
```

If you add `export PYTHONSTARTUP=/home/miki725/.pythonrc` to your `.bash_profile`, you can add that your `.pythonrc` file, and it'll be executed before an interactive prompt is shown as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that your `PYTHONPATH` is being modified when the [site](http://docs.python.org/release/2.4.3/lib/module-site.html) module is imported. Please have a look at the [user](http://docs.python.org/release/2.4.3/lib/module-user.html) module to provide user-specific configuration (basically just prepend the directories you're interested in to `sys.path`).

Note: `user` module is currently deprecated, but for python 2.4 this should work.

Edit: Just for completeness, for python >= 2.6 (`user` module deprecated), you should create a `usercustomize.py` file in your local `site-packages` directory as explained [here](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/interpreter.html#the-customization-modules).

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative approach, you could modify `sys.path` directly from the interpreter:

```
sys.path.insert(0,"/home/miki725/django/django")
```

Answer (score 0):

As indicated by others, you modify the `sys.path` directly in Python like this:

```
sys.path.insert(0,"/home/miki725/django/django")
```

But I think that [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) is the solution you are looking for. This tool allows you to create isolated Python environments.